# Do I need to use a try..catch block, and explicit rollback in a SQL Server procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I am coding a SQL Server (2008r2) procedure, and I wrap it in a transaction, do I need to explicitly enclose it in a try..catch block, and then explicitly call rollback in the catch block, or will it exit and rollback the same on its own?

i.e.:

How does this:

```
    begin transaction

    begin try
    delete from....

    insert into...
    end try
    begin catch
    rollback transaction
    return
    end catch

    commit transaction
```

Compare with:

```
    begin transaction
    delete from....

    insert into...
    commit transaction
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on the [`SET XACT_ABORT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx) setting:

> Specifies whether SQL Server automatically rolls back the current
> transaction when a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error.
>
> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a
> run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.
>
> When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL
> statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction
> continues processing. Depending upon the severity of the error, the
> entire transaction may be rolled back even when SET XACT_ABORT is OFF.
> **OFF is the default setting.**
>
> Compile errors, such as syntax errors, are not affected by SET
> XACT_ABORT.

For example, try the following code.  The first division by 0 raises an error but *continues execution*.  The second division by zero raises an error and halts execution:

```
begin transaction

set xact_abort off
    
select 1 / 0 -- causes divide by zero error, but continues
select @@trancount -- returns 1

set xact_abort on

select 1 / 0 -- causes divide by zero error and terminates execution
select @@trancount -- we never get here

rollback
```

If XACT_ABORT is ON, then errors will abort the transaction, and you don't need a TRY / CATCH.

If XACT_ABORT is OFF, you will need to check the status of each statement to see if an error occurred:

```
begin transaction

delete from...
if @@error <> 0
begin
    if @@trancount > 0
        rollback
    return
end

insert into...
if @@error <> 0
begin
    if @@trancount > 0
        rollback
    return
end

commit
```

However, if you ever find a case where you need to TRY / CATCH, you may need to do something special when the error occurs.  If so, don't forget to TRY / CATCH the exception handling:

```
begin transaction

set xact_abort on

begin try
    select 1 / 0 -- causes divide by zero error and terminates execution
    select @@trancount -- we never get here
    commit
end try
begin catch
    select xact_state() -- this will be -1 indicating you MUST rollback before doing any other operations
    select @@trancount -- this will probably be one, because we haven't ended the transaction yet
    if xact_state() <> 0
    begin try
        select 'rollback'
        rollback
        
        -- do something to handle or record the error before leaving the current scope
        select 'exception processing here'
        --insert into...
    end try
    begin catch
        -- ignore rollback errors
    end catch
    
end catch
```

Answer (score 4):

rollbacks will occur automatically if there is an error IN MOST CASES BUT NOT ALL

if you want to guarantee a rollback for all errors precede the begin transaction with SET XACT_ABORT ON

Best practice is to explicity catch errors with a try-catch block and take action there, including perhaps a rollback and reporting/logging the error.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the severity level of the error. Sufficiently high -- 16, perhaps? -- the process may stop at the failing line, leaving the transaction **open** and your locks in place. If there's any chance of error within a transaction, you definitely want to wrap it in the try-catch block, as you did in your first example.