# SQL Transaction uncommittable while using try..catch.. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2, try-catch

We're running into a problem here and I can't figure out why it behaves how it behaves.

Given the following two (simplified) stored procedures in TSQL (SQL Server 2008R2)

```
create procedure [datetransaction1] 
as
begin
    begin try
        begin transaction
        declare @a datetime
        exec datetransaction2 '2013-02-02 22:21', @a output
        select @a
        exec datetransaction2 '2013-020222:22', @a output
        select @a
        exec datetransaction2 '2013-02-02 22:23', @a output
        select @a

        commit transaction
    end try
    begin catch
        print 'Catch'
    end catch
end
```

and

```
create procedure [dbo].[datetransaction2] @text nvarchar(100), @res datetime OUTPUT  
AS
BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRY
        if (LEN(@text) = 16) SET @text = replace(@text, ' ', 'T') + ':00.000'
        else if (LEN(@text) = 19) SET @text = replace(@text, ' ', 'T') + '.000'
        else SET @text = replace(@text, ' ', 'T') 
        PRINT 'trydate:' + @text
        SELECT @res =convert(datetime, @text, 126)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ERROR_SEVERITY()
        PRINT 'errordate:' + @text
    END CATCH
END
```

If you then execute `exec datetransaction1`, we see that all 3 calls to `datetransaction2` are executed, with the first and last (as expected) running correctly, and the second one entering the `CATCH` block within `datetransaction2`.

So far, so good.

But then we land in the catch block of `datetransaction1` with the message that the transaction is uncommittable:

```
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure datetransaction1, Line 0
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.
Msg 3998, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.
```

Which isn't supposed to happen (I think). We caught the errors in the sub procedures, so why would the transaction suddenly become uncommittable?

Can someone explain that to me?

Note that we can probably find a way around this, but I'm intrigued more by the idea behind it. Why does this transaction suddenly become uncommittable here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason is: SQL Server dooms the transaction WHENEVER an error occurs, whatever the error is, whether it is in a TRY block or not, whether you saved a transaction state or not, whether the error occurs in a procedure or not, whatever you do.

When the error occurs in one of the procedure calls, the transaction is doomed. You can only rollback it completely (any savepoint will not help).

At the end, since the transaction is doomed, you cannot commit it...

Try this:

```
SET XACT_ABORT OFF -- pityful attempt to avoid the doom
BEGIN TRANSACTION
--
-- some useful TSQL instructions could be here
--
SAVE TRANSACTION SQL_SERVER_IS_GARBAGE -- another pityful attempt to do a partial restore
PRINT 'XACT_STATE='+CONVERT(varchar(10),XACT_STATE())
BEGIN TRY
  DECLARE @n int
  SELECT @n = CONVERT(int,'ABC') -- some very benign data error here (example)
  COMMIT TRANSACTION -- will never reach here
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
  PRINT 'XACT_STATE='+CONVERT(varchar(10),XACT_STATE())
  IF XACT_STATE()=-1 BEGIN
    PRINT 'The transaction is doomed, say thanks to Sql Server!'
    PRINT 'CANNOT restore to the save point!'
    -- You can just cry here and abort all, you lost all the useful work
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  END
  ELSE BEGIN
    -- would restore before the error if the transaction was not doomed
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION SQL_SERVER_IS_GARBAGE -- will never reach here either!
  END  
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks. Although it's not the answer I hoped for (I hoped there would be a solution..), it shows that there is no good answer to this question. Unfortunately.

Comment: This is simply not true. Calling SET XACT_ABORT OFF will leave the transaction in a commitable state for *some* errors. For example, although this particular conversion error is a real unrecoverable error, something like a primary key violation is not. After catching a primary key violation with SET XACT_ABORT OFF, the transaction remains in a committable state. Contrary to your assertion SQL server does not doom the transaction "whatever the error is", it only dooms it for certain kinds of errors.
Proof: http://imgur.com/a/M4KVU

Answer (score 4):

Since the second call to datetransaction2 function caused severity level 16 error SQL Server automatically rolled back your transaction. That's the reason for the error you are seeing.

Here is a [really nice article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2011/05/11/errors-raised-with-severity-level-16-may-cause-transactions-into-doomed-state.aspx) why the transactions gets into doomed state  when severity level 16 error occurs.

To verify that its getting rolled back automatically I added the following line to your datetransaction2 proc : print XACT_STATE()

```
  create procedure [dbo].[datetransaction2] @text nvarchar(100), @res datetime OUTPUT  
  AS
  BEGIN 
     print 'Start'
      print XACT_STATE() 
      BEGIN TRY
          if (LEN(@text) = 16) SET @text = replace(@text, ' ', 'T') + ':00.000'
          else if (LEN(@text) = 19) SET @text = replace(@text, ' ', 'T') + '.000'
          else SET @text = replace(@text, ' ', 'T') 
          PRINT 'trydate:' + @text
          SELECT @res =convert(datetime, @text, 126)
      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
           print XACT_STATE() 
           print 'Catch'
          PRINT ERROR_SEVERITY()
          PRINT 'errordate:' + @text
      END CATCH
      print XACT_STATE() 
      print 'End'
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the 'commit transaction' is never reached because the code jumps to the catch block. To Avoid this you can add a 'rollback transaction' to your catch block like so:

```
alter procedure [datetransaction1] 
as
begin
    begin try
        begin transaction
        declare @a datetime
        exec datetransaction2 '2013-02-02 22:21', @a output
        select @a
        exec datetransaction2 '2013-020222:22', @a output
        select @a
        exec datetransaction2 '2013-02-02 22:23', @a output
        select @a

        commit transaction
    end try
    begin catch
        print 'Catch'
         rollback transaction
    end catch
end
```

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem. The issue is that the catch block shouldn't be reached at all, as all errors are caught within their own procedures, so the main transaction shouldn't contain errors anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In short: a `catch` statement often causes a rollback (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950197/do-i-need-to-use-a-try-catch-block-and-explicit-rollback-in-a-sql-server-proce)). This depends on `XACT_ABORT`.
Next, rollbacks are not contained to the SP where they are initiated (see [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187844(v=sql.90).aspx)).

The first reference ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950197/do-i-need-to-use-a-try-catch-block-and-explicit-rollback-in-a-sql-server-proce)) gives a workaround using `@@trancount`, see the accepted answer there.

Comment: Hey, and welcome to SO! FYI, you can put code in teletype-font by enclosing it in backticks.

Comment: Thanks mohawkjohn. I didn't feel it necessary for the short bits of code, but indeed, it has quite a nice look!

Comment: Well, if you don't, there's a good chance other people will edit and do it for you. It's generally appreciated. Thank you. =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this particular error can only occur if Try/Catch is used.

Ultimately that error means a transaction was started and an error occurred that does not automatically cause a rollback.  There are numerous possible reasons.  The xact_abort setting being on (which is off by default) is only one.  You caught an error that didn't automatically roll back and you didn't roll the transaction back yourself.

Rather than understand what errors require rollback and when, personally, whether I start a transaction myself or not, I put the following code in EVERY catch block.

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

This definitively prevents the problem while insuring your data behaves exactly the way you would otherwise expect.  IOW always rollback on error.  Doing it consistently insures that it doesn't matter if some caller of your procedure started a transaction, you start one, or if some procedure you call starts one and leaves it dangling; it's always rolled back when you catch an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error like you and I realized that it happened because I'd started Tray before starting Transaction!
I changed their order so the problem has been solved!

```
 create procedure [datetransaction1] 
as
begin
     begin transaction
        begin try
            declare @a DateTime
            exec datetransaction2 '2013-02-02 22:21', @a output
            select @a
            exec datetransaction2 '2013-020222:22', @a output
            select @a
            exec datetransaction2 '2013-02-02 22:23', @a output
            select @a

    commit transaction
    end try
    begin catch
        print 'Catch'
    end catch
end
```

this is the best way to use try catch in a procedure:

> ```
> BEGIN TRY
>
>     DECLARE  @Trancount   INT
>     SET @TranCount = @@TRANCOUNT
>     IF @TranCount = 0
>
>     BEGIN TRAN [TransActionName]
>             
>         DECLARE @TErrMsg NVARCHAR(800)
>         
>         ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>         ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>         -- your code will go here
>
>         ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>         ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>         IF @TranCount = 0 
>             COMMIT TRAN [TransActionName]             
>                 RETURN
>
>     COMMIT TRAN [TransActionName]
> END TRY 
> BEGIN CATCH 
>     SET @TErrMsg = ( SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE())
>     IF @Trancount = 0 
>         ROLLBACK TRAN [TransActionName]
>     RAISERROR (@TErrMsg,18,1)
>     RETURN 
> END CATCH
> ```