# Mysterious error after exec into (insert into from stored procedure) when subordinate procedure fails: "current transaction cannot be committed"

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, sql-insert

I encountered a problem using T-SQL / SQL server (2017/140):

In my scenario there are a number of stored procedures (= worker procedures), which in turn perform different tasks and at the end output the result with a select statement.

A superordinate procedure (= runner procedure) calls the worker procedures one after the other and collects their result in a table using an insert-into statement.

Processing within the worker procedures is secured with try-/catch statements so that the runner procedure is not aborted if one of the worker procedures should fail. It is also ensured that the worker procedures always return a result, even if this procedure encounters an error during processing.

However, the runner procedure encounters an error if an error has occurred in a worker procedure, although this error has already been intercepted and handled in the worker procedure.
The error message is: „The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.“
As you can see from my example script, no explicit transactions are used there.

The problem only occurs when the results of the worker procedures are transferred to a table with a Select-Into statement. As an example I have created another runner procedure, which only executes the worker procedures, but does not transfer their results to a table. In this case there will be no errors.

```
CREATE SCHEMA bugchase;
GO

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS bugchase.worker_1;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS bugchase.worker_2;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS bugchase.runner_selectOnly;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS bugchase.runner_selectAndInsert;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE bugchase.worker_1
AS
BEGIN
    -- this worker just returns a value
    SELECT
        'Result Worker 1';
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE bugchase.worker_2
AS
BEGIN
    -- this worker encounters an error while processing.
    -- the error will be catched and some data will be returned

    DECLARE @result INT;

    BEGIN TRY
        -- this will force an error, because 'ABCD' could not be casted as float
        SET @result = CAST('ABCD' AS FLOAT);

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    -- just catch, don't do anything else

    END CATCH;

    SELECT
        'Result Worker 2';
END;
GO

CREATE PROC bugchase.runner_selectAndInsert
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @result AS TABLE (value NVARCHAR(64));

    -- exec worker_1 (no error will be thrown inside worker_1)
    PRINT 'Select&Insert: Worker 1 start';
    INSERT INTO @result (value)
    EXEC bugchase.worker_1;
    PRINT 'Select&Insert: Worker 1 end';

    -- exec worker_2 (will throw and catch an error inside)
    PRINT 'Select&Insert: Worker 2 start';
    INSERT INTO @result (value)
    EXEC bugchase.worker_2;
    PRINT 'Select&Insert: Worker 2 end';

END;
GO

CREATE PROC bugchase.runner_selectOnly
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- exec worker_1 (no error will be thrown inside worker_1)
    PRINT 'SelectOnly: Worker 1 start';
    EXEC bugchase.worker_1;
    PRINT 'SelectOnly: Worker 1 end';

    -- exec worker_2 (will throw and catch an error inside)
    PRINT 'SelectOnly: Worker 2 start';
    EXEC bugchase.worker_2;
    PRINT 'SelectOnly: Worker 2 end';


END;
GO

BEGIN TRY
    -- because all errors are catched within the worker-procedures, there should no error occur by this call
    EXEC bugchase.runner_selectAndInsert;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- indeed an error will occur while running worker 2
    PRINT CONCAT('Select&Insert: ERROR:', ERROR_MESSAGE());
END CATCH;
GO

BEGIN TRY
    -- for demonstration only, this will run as expected
    EXEC bugchase.runner_selectOnly;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- No error will occur
    PRINT CONCAT('SelectOnly: ERROR:', ERROR_MESSAGE());
END CATCH;
GO

DROP PROCEDURE bugchase.worker_2;
DROP PROCEDURE bugchase.worker_1;
DROP PROCEDURE bugchase.runner_selectOnly;
DROP PROCEDURE bugchase.runner_selectAndInsert;
DROP SCHEMA bugchase;
```

The script above will show the following result:

```
Select&Insert: Worker 1 start
Select&Insert: Worker 1 end
Select&Insert: Worker 2 start
Select&Insert: ERROR:
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file.
Roll back the transaction.
```

No error occurs, when the results are not stored into a table:

```
SelectOnly: Worker 1 start
SelectOnly: Worker 1 end
SelectOnly: Worker 2 start
SelectOnly: Worker 2 end
```

Comment: Don't have an answer for you, but yes that's a curious one... `DECLARE @result INT = CAST('ABCD' AS FLOAT);` and `DECLARE @result INT = CONVERT(FLOAT, 'ABCD');` both have that problem, despite being Level 16, State 5, however `DECLARE @result INT = 1/0;` which is Level 16, State 0, continues after the catch block to insert `'Result Worker 2'`.

Comment: The instruction "INSERT INTO @result (value) EXEC bugchase.worker_2" generates an implicit transaction in which the error with a severity level of 16 occurs.
This makes the transaction uncommittable despite of the empty catch block inside "worker_2" procedure so it's going to fail on autocommit.

Comment: The error related with "DECLARE @result INT = 1/0" doesn't change a value of XACT_STATE() with -1.

Comment: Thank you for the hints and information. The facts and causes are now at least clear. Ultimately, however, I would have expected that an error handled with try / catch should not have any side effects on objects outside the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1):

As Anton mentioned in the comments, this is a side effect of the autocommit functionality of SQL Server which is mentioned in the documentation for [SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Basically, with `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF` (the default), there are a bunch of statements that are automatically wrapped in an unseen transaction. `INSERT` is one of them, so anything that happens within the `INSERT INTO EXEC` is in one of these autocommit transactions. You can see this for yourself by printing or selecting @@trancount within one of the worker procs.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787678/sql-transaction-uncommittable-while-using-try-catch-why) has some great explanations of why the uncommittable transaction occurs even though you are catching the error.

In your case, you can work around this by rewriting the code to return data from the worker procs without using insert into. One simple option would be to replace your table variable in the runner proc with a temp table, then insert into that temp table within the worker procs instead of just selecting the result set.

e.g runner_selectAndInsert would become:

```
CREATE PROC bugchase.runner_selectAndInsert
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #result (value NVARCHAR(64));

    -- exec worker_1 (no error will be thrown inside worker_1)
    PRINT 'Select&Insert: Worker 1 start';
    EXEC bugchase.worker_1;
    PRINT 'Select&Insert: Worker 1 end';

    -- exec worker_2 (will throw and catch an error inside)
    PRINT 'Select&Insert: Worker 2 start';
    EXEC bugchase.worker_2;
    PRINT 'Select&Insert: Worker 2 end';

END;
```

and worker_1 would become:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bugchase.worker_1
AS
BEGIN
    -- this worker just returns a value
    INSERT INTO #result (value)
    SELECT
        'Result Worker 1';
END;
```

Some more options for passing data between procs like this are fleshed out by Erland Sommarskog [here](https://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I had already made an attempt to replace the table variable with a temporary variable. This worked well in the environment of my tests, in the productive scenario, in which many users and applications with a high number of threads made a lot of parallel calls to the runner procedure, this always leads to problems after a certain time that the temporary table cannot be created. Probably a consequence of connection sharing.

Comment: A solution with unique table names using dynamic SQL was successful, but no longer very transparent and subject to a certain overhead. Ultimately, I have now decided on a solution with a regular table in which the results of the worker procedures are assigned to the respective call using a key term.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach